# Linux kernel build - dont change vmlinuz

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, vmlinuz

When building an upstream kernel, `/boot/vmlinuz` and `/boot/System.Map` are updated to point at the newly installed kernel image. Is it possible to disable this behavior, perhaps by changing a config or Makefile parameter?

I'm building the kernel like this:

```
make oldconfig
make bzImage
make modules
make modules_install
make install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make install` calls `/sbin/installkernel` which will update the `vmlinuz` symlink. There is no option to disable this behavior. However, if you copy `/sbin/installkernel` to `~/bin/installkernel` you can remove the linking from that copy and `make install` uses this location for `installkernel` in preference to `/sbin/`.

In my version of `installkernel` it is this part of the `updatever` function:

```
 44   # This section is for backwards compatibility only
 45   if test -f "$dir/$1" ; then
 46     # The presence of "$dir/$1" is unusual in modern intallations, and
 47     # the results are mostly unused.  So only recreate them if they
 48     # already existed.
 49     if test -L "$dir/$1" ; then
 50         # If we were using links, continue to use links, updating if
 51         # we need to.
 52         if [ "$(readlink -f ${dir}/${1})" = "${dir}/${1}-${ver}" ]; then
 53             # Yup, we need to change
 54             ln -sf "$1-$ver.old" "$dir/$1.old"
 55         else
 56             mv "$dir/$1" "$dir/$1.old"
 57         fi
 58         ln -sf "$1-$ver" "$dir/$1"
 59     else                        # No links
 60         mv "$dir/$1" "$dir/$1.old"
 61         cat "$2" > "$dir/$1"
 62     fi
 63   fi
```

Personally, I don't use the `vmlinuz` and `System.Map` at all.